# Running Executable jar file keep hanging on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, executable-jar

I am very newbie in Jenkins, I've created Jenkins job where it will execute somekind like this jar command in Jenkins job:

```
ECHO **********************************

ECHO         Upgrade Devices

ECHO **********************************

cd c:\JenkinsPull

java -jar DevicesUpgrade.jar PC1 %ProjectName%
```

When I start to build the Jenkins job it able to run the DevicesUpgrade.jar file until last part of jar process before it finish, sudddenly it just stuck there till I abort the job.

So I think there must be a bug inside the jar file, but it is weird because after that, I tried to run `java -jar DevicesUpgrade.jar PC1 %ProjectName%` on command prompt, it didn't stuck at all and it able to finish up the jar.

Is there anything that I need to do on Jenkins to fix this hang problem?

**Here is the output I got from Jenkins:**

```
  c:\JenkinsPull>java -jar DevicesUpgrade.jar PC1 lex_l11_gms 

  %%%%f95eac91%%%%%

  lexl11g_64-ota-L11_D01.00.48_userdebug.zip

  1517844524458

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  adb -s shell f95eac91 "getprop | grep ro.build.version.incremental"

 \\ANDROIDTEST-05\ARM_png\JenkinsPull\BSP\lex_l11_gms\lexl11g_64-ota-
 L11_D01.00.48_userdebug.zip

 1.143848721E9

 [*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 --------------------------]
Here it keep loading the jenkins job till I need to abort the Jenkins job.
```

**Here is the output I got when I am running the jar via Command Prompt:**

```
  c:\JenkinsPull>java -jar DevicesUpgrade.jar PC1 lex_l11_gms 

  %%%%f95eac91%%%%%

  lexl11g_64-ota-L11_D01.00.48_userdebug.zip

  1517844524458

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  adb -s shell f95eac91 "getprop | grep ro.build.version.incremental"

 \\ANDROIDTEST-05\ARM_png\JenkinsPull\BSP\lex_l11_gms\lexl11g_64-ota-
 L11_D01.00.48_userdebug.zip

 1.143848721E9

 [*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 --------------------------]

 Upgrade Device Completed..!!

 c:\JenkinsPull>
```

Comment: can you provide console logs of build????

Comment: Did you try restarting the jenkins once and then try again running this job?? Mostly the script you are running is not returning to the jenkins after the execution.

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy yes I did restart Jenkins a few times, but it still kept returning the same thing..

Comment: Follow the `elimination strategy` and remove the lines causing and find out. It may help you. I can't see any wrong in jenkins. Can you please post some more info about jenkins job config???